# Add Dynamic Button in datagridView Rows Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am using WPF Application. I need to Create Button Dynamically with some properties and i add the buttons in dataGridView Rows. But Datatable is not Contains The Button DataType Then how to do this Please Someone Help me thanks in advance.

This is My Code:

```
DataTable NewDataTable = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < Row * level; i++)
{
    Button[] buttonArray = new Button[position];
    string Col1 = "Rows";
    string Col2 = "Levels";
    for (int j = 0; j < position; j++) 
    {                    
        if (j == 1) 
        {
            Col1 = "Rows";
        }
        else if (j == 2)
        {
            Col2 = "Levels";
        }
        else 
        {
            buttonArray[j] = new Button();
            buttonArray[j].Content = "Postion " + j;
            buttonArray[j].ToolTip = "Postion " + j;

        }                    
    }
    NewDataTable.Rows.Add(Col1, Col2, buttonArray[j]);
}
```

Code Behind

```
Dgrid.ItemsSource = NewDataGrid.DefaultView();
```

Comment: Well, if 'Datatable is not Contains' something then create a collection of custom objects which have required data and assign it to `ItemsSource`. There's rarely a place for DataTable in WPF app anyways. For further info and examples check out [MSDN-DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't yet met the [`DataGridTemplateColumn` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx). Let me introduce to you the column that can contain any controls in it... from the linked page:

> Represents a `DataGrid` column that hosts template-specified content in its cells.

An example, again from the linked page:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <!--DataTemplate for Published Date column defined in Grid.Resources.  PublishDate is a property on the ItemsSource of type DateTime -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DateTemplate" >
            <StackPanel Width="20" Height="30">
                <Border Background="LightBlue" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PublishDate, StringFormat={}{0:MMM}}" FontSize="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PublishDate, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy}}" FontSize="8" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <!--DataTemplate for the Published Date column when in edit mode. -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditingDateTemplate">
            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding PublishDate}"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--Custom column that shows the published date-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Publish Date" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DateTemplate}" CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource EditingDateTemplate}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created the following working example. Below is the code

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Binding="{Binding Col1}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2" Binding="{Binding Col2}" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ButtonsList">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Button Content="{Binding ButtonsList.Content}" ToolTip="{Binding ButtonsList.ToolTip}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

That is the Xaml part of the datagrid.

The Code behind file

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", Type.GetType("System.String")));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", Type.GetType("System.String")));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ButtonsList", Type.GetType("WpfApplication.ButtonsList")));
        dt.Rows.Add("Test1", "Test1", new ButtonsList { Content = "Test1", ToolTip = "Test1" });
        dt.Rows.Add("Test2", "Test2", new ButtonsList { Content = "Test2", ToolTip = "Test2" });
        dtGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

    }
```

As you can see that I created a new class for your button. You will run into problems if you directly add buttons to `DataGrid`. The extra class is very simple

```
public class ButtonsList
{
    public String Content { get; set; }
    public string ToolTip { get; set; }
}
```

Please check if it works.

You have to take care of property changes since I have not done any implementation